# angularjs orderBy default auto sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs

think of it like a to-do list, which has priority option. In my pushed `<li>`, I used `orderBy:priority` and it work fine. But later on I found the data I load from the back-end messed up its order. Like I push

```
1
2
3
a
```

then it may become

```
a
1
2
3
```

is angularjs auto sort list?

Comment: you dont want sorting than remove orderby filter.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed I want to sort by group, but the item within the group got sorted.

Comment: Could you show the definition of the todo object and the html you are using to display the list?